# Why is ResponseEntity body returning null?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to Java and creating APIs. I am trying to simply make a POST-request and get a specific value back. Here is my code:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WebService {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private static final String PROJECT_URL = "http://localhost:8080/project";

    public ResponseEntity<ProjectResponse> createProject(Project project) {
        ResponseEntity<ProjectResponse> completeProject = restTemplate.postForEntity(PROJECT_URL, project, ProjectResponse.class);
        System.out.println("Response body " + completeProject.getBody());
        return completeProject;
    }

}
```

And the ProjectResponse class simply has:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProjectResponse {
    private String id;
}
```

The problem is that id aøwaus gets returned as (id=null). Even though when I use "String" instead of ProjectResponse everything works fine and I see that the id is created. So for some reason there is a problem with mapping the response to the ProjectResponse-class.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: @billalGHILAS it already has `Data` annotation that performs the same

Comment: Does the response object you're getting back contain an `id` element?

Comment: yes, I see that the id-element is set when I convert everything to a string

Comment: @Nora have you tried override `toString()`?

Comment: I think you should use postforobject. Seems postforentity returns string but postforobject returns an object.

Comment: I will try! Does it matter that the response has many other fields also, and not just "id". Should responseEntity automatically map id to the id in the object because they have the same name?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and make your projectPesponse class the same as project.

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WebService {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private static final String PROJECT_URL = "http://localhost:8080/project";

    public ResponseEntity<Project> createProject(Project newProject) {
        Project completeProject = restTemplate.postForObject(PROJECT_URL, newProject, Project.class);
        log("Response body " + completeProject.getBody());//Log this instead
         return ResponseEntity.ok(completeProject);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and handle the exception here to make class ResponseErrorHandler and implement the ResponseErrorHandler(i)

```
@Component
public class WebService {

private RestTemplate restTemplate;
private static final String PROJECT_URL = "http://localhost:8080/project";

public ProjectResponse createProject(Project project) {

ProjectResponseErrorHandler errorHandler = new ProjectResponseErrorHandler(
project.getId());
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    ResponseEntity<ProjectResponse> completeProject = restTemplate.postForEntity(PROJECT_URL, project, ProjectResponse.class);
  log("Response body " + completeProject.getBody());
    return completeProject.getBody();
}
}
```